# C++ Efficiently creating map with single entry being different

Tags: c++, dictionary

Given a master copy of a map with `n` entries, which is expensive to copy.  I need to change the value of entry in the map one at a time and perform some operation on the new map.  I wonder if there is an efficient way to achieve it without having to copy the master map `n` times.

In the following code, `XYZ` is a class that is expensive to copy and the operation that I need to perform is not necessary summation.  I chose summation for an illustration purpose.

```
class BigMap
{
private:
  std::map<int, XYZ> m;
public
  std::map<int, XYZ>::const_iterator begin() const
  {
    return m.begin();
  }
  std::map<int, XYZ>::iterator begin()
  {
    return m.begin();
  }
  std::map<int, XYZ>::const_iterator end() const
  {
    return m.end();
  }
  std::map<int, XYZ>::iterator end()
  {
    return m.end();
  }
  void PopulateBigMapWithLotsOfData(int size)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      m[i] = XYZ();
    }
  }
};

double Aggregate(const BigMap& bm)
{
  double result = 0.0;
  for (const auto& entry : bm)
  {
    result += entry.second.Value();
  }
}

int main()
{
  BigMap bm;
  bm.PopulateBigMapWithLotsOfData(1000);

  double result = 0.0;
  // This for loop will be in a multi-threaded environment.
  // Thus I do need a shallow copy of bm in each thread.
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    BigMap newBm(bm);  // An expensive copy

    newBm[i].ChangeValue();  // Modify single entry

    result += Aggregate(newBm);  // Perform some operation on the new map
  }

  return result;
}
```

I am thinking of something like the following, but I got stuck on the iterator part as the `Aggregate` function needs to be able to loop through all entries of the map with the `begin` and `end` iterator being defined.

```
class BigMap
{
public:
  XYZ& Find(int index)
  {
    return ptr->Find(index);
  }

  const XYZ& Find(int index) const
  {
    return ptr->Find(index);
  }
private:
  AbstractBigMap* ptr;  // Pointer so that I can apply virtual function.
};

class AbstractBigMap
{
public:
  virtual XYZ& Find(int index);
  virtual const XYZ& Find(int index) const;
}

class OriginalBigMap : public AbstractBigMap
{
public:
  XYZ& Find(int index)
  {
    return m.find(index)->second;
  }

  const XYZ& Find(int index) const
  {
    return m.find(index)->second;
  }
private:
  std::map<int, XYZ> m;
};

class ModifiedBigMap : public AbstractBigMap
{
public:
  // Reference on the original map to avoid copying.
  ModifiedBigMap(const OriginalBigMap& original, int index)
    : _original(original), _index(index)
  {
    // Copy single entry from the original map so we can modify it
    _m[index] = _original.m.find(index)->second;
  }

  XYZ& Find(int index)
  {
    assert(index == _index);

    return _m[index].second;
  }

  const XYZ& Find(int index) const
  {
    if (index == _index)
      return _m[index].second;
    else
      return _original.Find(index);
  }
private:
  const OriginalBigMap& _original;
  std::map<int, XYZ> _m;
  int _index;
};
```

Basically the entry with a particular key from the original map should never get accessed as it is replaced by the single entry in `_m`.

Edit:
I should have pointed out the for loop is in fact in a multi-threaded environment so I can't simply make a copy of the entry and replace it after the operation.

Comment: Unless I didn't get your question properly, why not modify the map, do the required operation, and undo the modification. And keep repeating this.

Comment: It's not necessary very easy to undo the operation.  Also, the modification followed by the operation will be in a multi-threaded environment too.

Comment: if you know how much map you need you should have the n copies at start time because it will cost you a lot especially with bigmap.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating `n` copies of the map as the value type is expensive to copy.

Comment: Would it be true to claim that if your "bm" map could be presented as concatenation of two sub maps {bm1,bm2} then `Aggregate(bm)` is equal to `Aggregate(bm1) + Aggregate(bm2)`?

Answer (score 1):

**You may replace a value at some position in your map while invoking a function:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Map>
struct Invoke
{
    using value_type = typename Map::mapped_type;
    using const_iterator = typename Map::const_iterator;

    const_iterator position;
    value_type replace_value;

    Invoke(const_iterator position, value_type replace_value)
    :   position(position), replace_value(replace_value)
    {}

    template <typename Function>
    value_type operator () (const Map& map, const Function& function) const
    {
        value_type result = value_type();
        for(auto pos = map.begin(); pos != map.end(); ++pos) {
            if(pos == position) result = function(result, replace_value);
            else result = function(result, pos->second);
        }
        return result;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    using map_type = std::map<int, int>;
    map_type map = { {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2} };
    for(auto pos = map.begin(); pos != map.end(); ++pos) {
        Invoke<map_type> invoke(pos, -1);
        std::cout << invoke(map, std::plus<int>()) << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Alternatively, you may use a custom iterator:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Iterator>
struct ReplaceIterator
{
    public:
    using iterator = Iterator;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag ;
    using difference_type = typename iterator::difference_type;
    using value_type = typename iterator::value_type;
    using reference = typename iterator::reference;
    using pointer = typename iterator::pointer;


    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    explicit ReplaceIterator(iterator position, iterator replace_position, value_type replace_value)
    :   m_position(position), m_replace_position(replace_position), m_replace_value(replace_value)
    {}


    // Element Access
    // ==============

    public:
    const iterator& position() const { return m_position; }
    reference& value() const {
        return (m_position == m_replace_position)
            ? m_replace_value
            : *m_position;
    }

    // Iterator
    // ========

    public:
    reference operator * () const { return value(); }
    pointer operator -> () const { return &value(); }

    ReplaceIterator& operator ++ () {
        ++m_position;
        return *this;
    }
    ReplaceIterator operator ++ (int) {
        ReplaceIterator tmp(*this);
        ++m_position;
        return tmp;

    }

    // Compare
    // =======

    public:
    friend bool operator == (const ReplaceIterator& a, const ReplaceIterator& b) {
        return a.m_position == b.m_position;
    }

    friend bool operator == (const iterator& a, const ReplaceIterator& b) {
        return a == b.m_position;
    }

    friend bool operator == (const ReplaceIterator& a, const iterator& b) {
        return a.m_position == b;
    }

    friend bool operator != (const ReplaceIterator& a, const ReplaceIterator& b) {
        return a.m_position != b.m_position;
    }

    friend bool operator != (const iterator& a, const ReplaceIterator& b) {
        return a != b.m_position;
    }

    friend bool operator != (const ReplaceIterator& a, const iterator& b) {
        return a.m_position != b;
    }

    private:
    iterator m_position;
    iterator m_replace_position;
    mutable value_type m_replace_value;
};



int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    using map_type = std::map<int, int>;
    map_type map = { {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2} };
    for(auto pos0 = map.begin(); pos0 != map.end(); ++pos0) {
        int result = 0;
        ReplaceIterator<map_type::const_iterator> pos1(map.begin(), pos0, {0, -1});
        for( ; pos1 != map.end(); ++pos1)
            result += pos1->second;
        std::cout << result << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Both will print:**

```
2
1
0
```

Comment: It's a great idea. Except my for loop will be in a multi-threaded environment. I edited the post to reflect that. thanks!

Comment: Cool! I think I can use your `ReplaceIterator` idea in my `ModifiedBigMap` to achieve what I want!  I will try it out!

Comment: @user4148224 Note: Both solutions are thread-safe, as long as the underlying container is not mutated

Answer (score 1):

How about saving the the value before it is changed and then restoring:

```
  double result = 0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    //BigMap newBm(bm);  // An expensive copy

    // save the value
    XYZ temp(bm[i]);

    //newBm[i].ChangeValue();  // Modify single entry
    bm[i].ChangeValue();

    result += Aggregate(bm);  // Perform some operation on the modified map

    // restore the saved value
    bm[i] = temp;
  }
```

Comment: It's a great idea.  Except my for loop will be in a multi-threaded environment.  I edited the post to reflect that.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do with the copy and about probabilities that you will actually do a lot of change.
How about this: create another class that stores a reference to your map and also a sparse structure that is able to store the same data.
Whenever something is accessed, you first check if the sparse structure contains the datum and if not, the reference is used. (this has some disadvantages, depending on what exactly you want to do)

Comment: Agreed.  That's what I did with the `ModifiedBigMap` class.  I guess my issue is in my 'Aggregate' function, I only take an input of type `BigMap`, which can contain either `OriginalBigMap` or `ModifiedBigMap`.  And I need to somehow have an iterator that will loop through the `ModifiedBigMap` and point to the entry from `_m` if the `index` is the same, followed by going back to the referenced `OriginalBigMap` when we preform `++` operation on the iterator.